# Linq datatable does not contain the definition of AsParallel C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, async-await, plinq

i am getting error "datatable does not contain the definition of AsParallel
in my Linq Query. pls tell me how to fix this what i am doing wrong.

```
var results = from myRow in dtTaskandBugs.AsParallel()
                          select myRow;
            results.ForAll(async r =>
            {
                Task<int> storyProcessing = GetStoryid(r["Id"]);
                Task<int> fidProcessing = Fidname(r["Storyid"]);
                Task<string> featureProcessing = r["FeatureID"].ToString() == "0" ? Task.FromResult("Anonymous") : fname(r["FeatureID"]);
                r["Storyid"] = await storyProcessing;
                r["FeatureID"] = await fidProcessing;
                r["FeatureName"] = await featureProcessing;
            });
```

Comment: With the answer below it would appear to work - but you still call a bunch of `async void` mehods in parallel. You have no grip on when this completes and all exceptions will disappear in the mist.

Comment: Do read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions?view=netframework-4.7.1) it appears `AsParallel` isn't an extension on the `DataTable` class. You may want to go through the `AsEnumerable` method and then parallelize as you need.

```
var results = from myRow in dt.TaskandBugs.AsEnumerable().AsParallel() select myRow;
results.ForAll(async r => ...
```

See if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: A direct and correct solution to a bad (XY) question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I did have concerns about that and I realize now that I wrote "parallelize as you need" instead of if you need as I thought I had done.